# bootstrap collapse navigation not working in my wordpress theme in mobile

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mobile, twitter-bootstrap

bootstrap collapse navigation  not working  in my wordpress theme in mobile 
when i use it on mobile/iphone the menus  hide behind the used image-icon but when I clicked on this image it does not collapse and not show the all list item.

```
   <div class="container">
<div style="position: static;" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
              <a data-target="navbar-inverse-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="brand"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/spa_logo.png" alt="spasalon" /></a>
               <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-inverse-collapse">

                  <?php
          if ( has_nav_menu( 'header-menu' ) ):

          wp_nav_menu( array(  'menu'       => 'header-menu',
                       'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
                       'depth'      => 3,
                       'container'  => false,
                       'menu_class' => 'nav',
                       'menu_id'=>'a',
                       'show_home'=>'HOME',
                      'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu', 

                        'walker' => new twitter_bootstrap_nav_walker()
                        )
                        );


      endif; ?> 


     </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
          </div><!-- /navbar-inner -->
        </div>
```

Comment: Have you looked into https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4497

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding bootstrap-collapse.js as an individual file to wp_register_script() in your function file. And make sure you are adding bootstrap.min.js as well properly. I had this same issue and then properly enqueued my js files and then it is now working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution while creating theme for my [blog](http://teckstack.com) .

Script to be added...

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

- Please go to **functions.php** file into themes folder and ADD below function.

  ```
  function tsbs2013_scripts_with_jquery(){

      // Register the script like this for a theme:
      wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

      // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
      wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
  }

  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tsbs2013_scripts_with_jquery' );
  ```

Comment: Please don't just post a link as an answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I have added description in my answer. Can you please upvote now?